# find number of routes between two cells

Tags: java

here's the exercise:
i need to write recursive method which gets matrix with positive int numbers in n*n size, starting cell row and column indexes and finishing cell row and column indexes and the method need to return the number of possible routes from starting cell to finishing cell with these constraints:
a.you can move to the left cell,right cell,upper cell or lower cell from your current position
b.you cant cross the main diagonal, yet you can go to cells on the diagonal(but not cross it).
c.every cell in the route occurs only once.
d. the matrix needs to be like the original matrix with original cell values at the end

here's what i got so far:

```
public static int numPaths (int[][] mat,int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        if(x1>y1 || x2>y2 || y1<x1 || y2<x2) return 0;
        return numPaths(mat ,x1, y1, x2, y2, x1, y1);
    }
    public static int numPaths (int[][] mat ,int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int row, int col){
        if(row<0 || col <0 || row>=mat.length || col>=mat.length ) return 0;
        if(row==x2 && col==y2){ 
            return 1;
        }
        if(row==col){ 
            return numPaths ( mat ,x1, y1, x2, y2, row, col+1) + numPaths( mat ,x1, y1, x2, y2, row-1,col);

        }
        else{
            return numPaths( mat ,x1, y1, x2, y2, row, col+1) + numPaths( mat ,x1, y1, x2, y2, row+1, col)+
                    numPaths( mat ,x1, y1, x2, y2, row-1, col) + numPaths( mat ,x1, y1, x2, y2, row, col-1);    
            }

        }
```

but i get stack overflow error because i cant make the difference when i visited the cell before. i am sure that there is a way to change the value in cell in recursive method and bring it back to normal later on but i cant think of a way how to do that.

please advise

Comment: You never refer to any values in the matrix. Is that correct? If so, why pass it in to the method at all? Is this just intending to find all potential paths through half a matrix? If so it's definitely going to stack overflow for large matrices as the number of potential paths increases exponentially. Try it for small matrices with a known number of paths to make sure it behaves before trying anything large.

Answer (score 0):

If you are intending to use the matrix to store whether a cell has been visited then best make it a boolean matrix. Then it's a simple matter of setting the value to true before recursing and then false afterwards.

Something like the following should work. I've moved variables to the class because it seemed unnecessary to be passing them around.

So something like:

```
private final int size;
private final boolean visited[][] = new boolean[size][size];

public int numPaths(int x, int y) {
    if (visited[x][y] || x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= size || y >= size)
        return 0;
    if (x == size - 1 && y == size - 1)
        return 1;
    visited[x][y] = true;
    int numPaths = 0;
    numPaths += numPaths(x - 1, y) + numPaths(x, y - 1);
    if (x != y)
        numPaths += numPaths(x + 1, y) + numPaths(x, y + 1;
    visited[x][y] = false;
    return numPaths;
}
```